# Creating JS event from pure css implementation of radio button slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following pure html and css implementation of a radio slider. What is a good way of creating a javascript event based on the toggle function? I can see a few approaches to poll the component and get it's position, however, I am not sure how to get the change to trigger a callback etc. Thanks.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

body {
  color: #404040;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #3b3f46;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 90px 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: false;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), transparent);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), transparent);
  background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center, cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), transparent);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center, cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), transparent);
  background-image: radial-gradient(center, cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), transparent);
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  height: 26px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 58px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-label:active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.switch-label-off {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.switch-label-on {
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.switch-input {
  display: none;
}

.switch-input:checked + .switch-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
  -moz-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
  -ms-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
  -o-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
  transition-property: color, text-shadow;
}

.switch-input:checked + .switch-label-on ~ .switch-selection {
  left: 60px;
  /* Note: left: 50%; doesn't transition in WebKit */
}

.switch-selection {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 58px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #65bd63;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #9dd993), color-stop(100%, #65bd63));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="switch">
    <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="week" id="week" checked>
    <label for="week" class="switch-label switch-label-off">ON</label>
    <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="month" id="month">
    <label for="month" class="switch-label switch-label-on">OFF</label>
    <span class="switch-selection"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
if (document.getElementById('week').checked) {
  //task to perform when "ON"
}
else
{
  //task to perform when "OFF"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I believe that mean I have to go and check the slider. I was hoping to trigger an event/callback, so I can continue doing the stuff I need to on my page, but whenever the user clicks the slider I can trigger a function to update my page content